# Regex: Only match if one word of both wordlist are present

Tags: regex

I am trying to apply a regex filter on news headlines. I want the filter only to match, if at least **one word of both wordlists** are present in the news headline. Furthermore, it should only generate 1 match (not multiple matches if some tokens apply).

These are my wordlists (and my regex which doesnt work currently):

```
(Threat actor|attack|skimm|malware|exploit|fraud|inject|trojan|ransom|\bRCE\b)+(\bATM\b|bank|\bAustria\b)
```

**The regex should only match, if "ATM", "bank" or "Austria" AND a word from the first list (in the paranthesis) is present in the news headline, not if only "ATM", ... is present.**

Example: A match should only appear, if "exploit" AND "ATM" is encountered in the headline.

Given the four headlines below, only headline 2 should return a match.

> 1. An APT Group **Exploit**ing a 0-day in FatPipe WARP, MPVPN, and IPVPN
>    Software
> 2. Ares **Malware**: The Grandson of the Kronos Banking Trojan that targets
>    German Flag of Germany **Banks**.
> 3. In human-operated **ransomware** attacks, **threat actor**s use predictable
>    methods to enter a device but eventually rely on hands-on-keyboard
>    activities.
> 4. Kotak Mahindra **Bank** launches new transactions across India

Example 1 has only a word of the first list. Example 4 has only a word of the second list.

**Only example 2 has occurences of words of BOTH lists.**

Example 3 has also 2 two occurences of the *first* list, but none of the second list, therefore NO MATCH.

I would be very grateful if you could provide a working regex filter for this case.

Regards, Michael

Answer (score 1):

You could match both groups in both ways:

```
(Threat actor|attack|skimm|malware|exploit|fraud|inject|trojan|ransom|\bRCE\b).*(\bATM\b|bank|\bAustria\b)|(\bATM\b|bank|\bAustria\b).*(Threat actor|attack|skimm|malware|exploit|fraud|inject|trojan|ransom|\bRCE\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PJGgZK/1)